# How to remove and replace a reference to the Ecommerce plugin with enhanced ecommerce code in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I read at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce that "the Enhanced Ecommerce plug-in should not be used alongside the Ecommerce (ecommerce.js) plug-in for the same property." In my case, I already implemented Ecommerce tracking and want to start using Enhanced Ecommerce tracking. The link I mentioned above explains that one of the options I have is to migrate from the ecommerce plug-in to the enhanced ecommerce plug-in. I need to remove and replace references to the Ecommerce plugin with enhanced ecommerce code.

This is Ecommerce (not Enhanced Ecommerce) code:

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '1234',
    'revenue': '11.99'
});
```

How could I convert that into Enhanced Ecommerce? Would this be correct?:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': '1234',
    'revenue': '37.39'
});
```

I was reading https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions and I see that under the "Measuring Actions" heading, they use `ga('ec:addProduct', {.....}` before `ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {.....}` but I guess in my case for the conversion of my code that I need from Ecommerce to Enhanced Ecommerce, it would not be necessary the `addProduct` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce:

```
// Transaction level information is provided via an actionFieldObject.
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', { <?php // The product action 'purchase' is used to send data about the sale of one or more products. ?>
  'id': '<?php echo $id ?>', <?php // The transaction ID. It is required because the type of transaction is 'purchase'. ?>
  'affiliation': '<?php echo $affiliation; ?>',
  'revenue': '<?php echo $revenue ?>' <?php // Specifies the total revenue or grand total associated with the transaction. ?>
});
```